# Create a new custom visual Power BI from template

Tags: powerbi

With the next command:
*pbiviz new sampleCorrPlotRVisual -t rvisual*

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/RVisualTutorial/CreateNewVisual.md

I can create a new visualization  based on R .
 
My question is if I can to create a visualizations based on another template. I don't know if this is possible.
 
Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

Templates seem to be stored in `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\powerbi-visuals-tools\templates\visuals`.

I have a `table` template there as well.

Comment: Yes, I know it... but... Are there more templates??? (I have table and list templates)

Comment: "My question is if I can to create a visualizations based on another template" - Yes, all the templates you can create with -t parameter are stored in that folder.